Help identify an old sci fi
I was a young teenager in the 80's.  I watched a movie where a guy could see people weren't people when he wore (special) glasses.  At the end they got him and you got a view through his glasses (of what he saw) when they got knocked off.
Now I know I was a young and impressional child but the film wasnt the John Carpenter one as I've seen that since and it wasn't that.
I always thought it was a 60's or 70's film- in colour.  It's bugged me for years.  I'm a sci fi fan and to this day I can't remember what it was called.
Anyone any ideas??
